# Is it obligatory for a Muslim to help Muslims in need in another country?

Tags: obligation, deeds

Suppose some Muslims in another country need help, e.g. in a war, in an earthquake.

Is it obligatory for Muslims in other countries to help them?

What about a situation when the government, who could have Islamic rules, has banned it?

*Reference from Quran and hadith would be appreciated.*

Comment: depends on how you define Muslim and Islam an Islamic government. for example if Takfiri groups like Al-Qaede are defined as Muslims or not?

Answer (score 2):

Of course yes. When a Muslim brother or a sister needs help, we have to help. But as much as we can. Even with dua, or sending money and... . But if you wanted and you couldn’t, it’s OK. In your example, you government doesn't let you to help them, you should try again but if you couldn’t, its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in Islam you must always help another brother or sister no matter where they are from if they are in need of help and you are able to help them.

Also you should be happy about helping them because their dua is getting answered through you and Allah will reward you for your help.

It is also good to help non-Muslims not just Muslims. There is a Hadith which even says being kind or helping and animal can get you into heaven.

Comment: can you give me some hadith or quranic verse about it ? especially for your last sentence.

Comment: Hmmm, @Aisha, On the whole, what you said can be considered as an approved response and even it deserve +1 owing to showing Islam as a peaceful religion. (Of course your answer would be better if you add at least a hadith as Abdullah said {for ur last sentence). anyhow well done mate. God Bless You.